# Terraform code for GCP Cloud DNS A recordset - Geo Based Routing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-dns

I'm trying to create a dns recordset with geo based routing policy that will be managed by terraform. Please can anyone share a sample code for the same.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform does not support Google Cloud DNS Routing Policies at this time.

The Terraform **google_dns_record_set** has not been extended to support routing policy.

[google_dns_record_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/dns_record_set)